# Add Multiple UICollectionView in UIScrollView with Paging by using single ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

I would like to have a paging `UIScrollView` with five `UICollectionView` that each have different data. Is it possible with one `ViewController`?

Comment: Yes Possible. You can do it.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: I have tried adding the collectionview as a subview which shows the data but won't allow me to do any user interaction.

Comment: @McDonal_11 how do you go about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes Possible.

You have to create 5 `UICollectionView` inside `UIScrollView's` `ContentView` [ContentView means, you have to create `UIView` inside `UIScrollView` with same `UIScrollView's` frame. Then, each `UICollectionView` should be inside within that `ContentView`] having width as `UIScrollView's` Width

Each X position of `UICollectionView` should have difference as `UIScrollView's` Width

> Suppose, your UIScrollView frame is: {0,0,375,500},  1st CollectionView Frame: = {0,0,375,500} 2nd CollectionView Frame: = {375,0,375,500} 3rd CollectionView Frame: = {750,0,375,500} and goes on...

Then, you have to enable paging in `UIScrollView`.

Then, you have to give `UIScrollView's` content size as, **width** = {number_of_collectionviews * UICollectionView's width} and **height** = 500

Thats it.